# IntelliJ Haskforce plugin - run error

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea

I installed the Community edition of IntelliJ and the HaskForce Haskell plugin, and I find that:

1. It does not do any of the context sensitive formatting or auto-completions shown on the demo page,
2. There is not any obvious simple run configuration for Haskell
   and trying to use a default configuration gives the error:

   *"Error running Pgm: no JDK specified"*

Doing a build is successful, and creates a Pgm.exe in the ./dist/build/Pgm directory.
Is there some additional setup or configuration needed?

Comment: I have 0 experience with IntelliJ and Haskforce, but it looks like you need an install of the JDK and you'll have to point IntelliJ at it.  Have you tried that?

Comment: This is not the issue; Java examples run fine - and anyway a Haskell execution does not require a JDK.

Answer (score 2):

In your project settings -> Haskell Tools, you haven't specified paths to all executables, in particular ghc-mod and ghc-modi.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense for the editing features - but probably not the JDK issue? This dependency should be noted in the Install notes. Trying to install it, gives an error; `"Compiling Browse; Not in scope: data constructor ExplicitForall' Perhaps you meantExplicitForAll' (imported from Language.Haskell.Exts.Extension)"` SO23277995 mentions this, and from that trying to install ghc-mod-4.0.2, then another posting with ghc-mod install problems notes a newer version (5.2.1.2), which then also fails: `"Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps)."` I give up - stuck in cabal hell.

Comment: @guthrie Not sure about the JDK message. As for ghc-mod issues, make sure to install it in a sandbox.

Comment: I think the current version of Cabal does this by default; but cabal seems broken itself.